# Where to display value in checkbox after explode

Tags: php, html

Below I have a text input:

```
'<input type=\"text\" name=\"indivoptions\" class=\"options\" id=\"answer".$option."\" name=\"answerName[$option]\" value=\"$option\" />'
```

Now I want to display each `$option` after explode in a text input, not a general string output but where do I put the code above in the code below?

```
  $options = explode('-', $option);
  if(count($options) > 1) {
    $start = array_shift($options);
    $end = array_shift($options);
    do {
      $options[] = $start;
    }while(++$start <= $end);
  }
```

Current Code:

```
function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
  $options = explode('-', $option);
  foreach($options as $answers) {
  $answers = '<p><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"anstype\" class=\"answers\" id=\"answer".$option."\" name=\"answerName[$option]\" value=\"$option\" />$option</p>';
}
  if(count($options) > 1) {
    $start = array_shift($options);
    $end = array_shift($options);
    do {
      $options[] = $start;
    }while(++$start <= $end);
  }
  else{
    $options = explode(' or ', $option);
  }
  return implode(" ", $options);
}
```

Comment: Why are you escaping your quotes?

Comment: @jtheman I just saw it written this way as an example in php

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = explode('-', $option);
foreach($options as $indivOption) {
  // do something with each option ($indivOption)
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am planning to change it from text input to checkboxes in stead but anyway when I tried your solution, each option does not appear as a checkbox, I included a current code section below the question

Comment: You almost got, what the code does above is it retrieves indvidual options in a full option type. So for example if `$option` is `A-D`, then by using the explode, it will be able to display each individual option to output `A B C D`. Now In this example I want `A B C D` to each have it's own checkbox. But with your code it is just creating checkbox for `A` and `D`, the first and last options

Comment: well, actually you do not understand what explode() stands for. it splits strings to build arrays. if the string is 'A-D', then the array consists of two values: [0 => 'A', 1 => 'D']. It does not fill in the 'B' and the 'C' whatsoever

Comment: Ah, ok learned something new, so do you know how to get all options containing its own checkbox

Comment: Are you going to finish your answer off?